# Compute slopes from xy coordinates per group in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have an `xy` `data.frame`, along with other `factor`s, for example:

```
df <- data.frame(y = c(0.05, -0.03, -0.13, -0.24, 0.05, -0.03, -0.13, -0.24, 0.59, 1.97, 2.26, 1.89, 0.59, 1.97, 2.26, 1.89),
                      x = c(0, 1.58, 2, 4.58, 0, 1.58, 2, 4.58, 0, 1.58, 2, 4.58, 0, 1.58, 2, 4.58),
                      sex = c('F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M'),
                      group = c('B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'))
```

I'm looking for a `function` (probably usage of `dplyr` would work best) that will compute the slopes (which are the difference in `y` divided by the difference of `x`, between each pair of consecutive `x` points), for each level of each of the factors in `df`. In the case of this example, I will have 4 groups of slopes: for `group  = A` and `sex = F`, `group  = A` and `sex = M`, `group  = B` and `sex = F`, and for `group  = B` and `sex = M`.

If possible, it would be nice if the solution is generic such that it applies to more `factors` than what is specified in this example (with the condition that all factors are of class `factor`).

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find the slope (per your definition) using `dplyr` the `lag()` function may be of use.

The `lead` and `lag` functions:

> Find the "next" or "previous" values in a vector. Useful for comparing values ahead of or behind the current values.

In order to implement grouping by your factor variables, you can first use `dplyr::group_by()`. This is generalisable and can accept one or more grouping variables.

Below is a reproducible example that shows this calculation for each group.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- data.frame(y = c(0.05, -0.03, -0.13, -0.24, 0.05, -0.03, -0.13, -0.24, 0.59, 1.97, 2.26, 1.89, 0.59, 1.97, 2.26, 1.89),
                 x = c(0, 1.58, 2, 4.58, 0, 1.58, 2, 4.58, 0, 1.58, 2, 4.58, 0, 1.58, 2, 4.58),
                 sex = c('F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M'),
                 group = c('B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'))

df %>% 
  group_by(sex, group) %>% 
  mutate(slope = (y - lag(y)) / (x - lag(x)))
#> # A tibble: 16 x 5
#> # Groups:   sex, group [4]
#>          y     x sex   group    slope
#>      <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <fct>    <dbl>
#>  1  0.0500  0.   F     B      NA     
#>  2 -0.0300  1.58 F     B      -0.0506
#>  3 -0.130   2.00 F     B      -0.238 
#>  4 -0.240   4.58 F     B      -0.0426
#>  5  0.0500  0.   M     B      NA     
#>  6 -0.0300  1.58 M     B      -0.0506
#>  7 -0.130   2.00 M     B      -0.238 
#>  8 -0.240   4.58 M     B      -0.0426
#>  9  0.590   0.   F     A      NA     
#> 10  1.97    1.58 F     A       0.873 
#> 11  2.26    2.00 F     A       0.690 
#> 12  1.89    4.58 F     A      -0.143 
#> 13  0.590   0.   M     A      NA     
#> 14  1.97    1.58 M     A       0.873 
#> 15  2.26    2.00 M     A       0.690 
#> 16  1.89    4.58 M     A      -0.143
```

Created on 2018-09-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).